# Comparing performance before and after optimization

Tags: mean, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have data of program performance before and after an optimization of this program. The program was run indipendently several times before and after. 
I calculated the quotient of runtime per database size to have an estimate of the performance.

seconds/gigabyte:
1.52
0.21
0.66
0.71
0.02
0.33
0.27
0.40
0.20
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
2.58
0.01
0.00
1.64

arithmetic mean: 0.50

std: 7.383407471·10-1

The distribution is normal with a confidence of: 0.01% (Anderson-Darling normality test)

[image: histogram of values before optimization, sec/gb]

---

seconds/gigabyte:

0.11
0.01
0.01
0.00
0.21
0.05
0.17
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.14
0.06
0.15

arithmetic mean: 0.07

std: 7.626707459·10-2

The distribution is normal with a confidence of: 2.38% (Anderson-Darling normality test)

[image: histogram of values after optimization, sec/gb]

I wonder which mean would be the most suitable to compare these quotients and why? I chose the arithmetic because both database size and runtime vary per run of the program (or is this irrelevant? ^^).

I used an online anderson-darling-normality-test I think this indicates both are not normally distributed.  Would a t-test be advisable?

I performed a Wilcoxon Rank Sum test to test for the null hypothesis that the performance is identical. I cannot reject this hypothesis because the p=0.1022. Is this correct?